# populate jquery form from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am attempting to populate a jquery form with data from an XML where the XML has an id that will populate a dropdown in the form and upon selection of an id other form fields will be populated. BTW I will not be using PHP

My XML

```
<XMLReview>
<plan>
 <planNumber>773</planNumber> 
 <Area>Upper Missouri</Area> 
 <ID>MISSOURI-NUT</ID> 
 <Name>Missouri River</Name> 
 <code>10030101</code> 
 <County>Broadwater</County> 
 <Station_ID>M09MISSR05</Station_ID> 
</plan>
<plan>
 <planNumber>774</planNumber> 
 <Area>Columbia</Area> 
 <ID>FLAT-STILL-TPA-2013</ID> 
 <Name>Sheppard Creek</Name> 
 <Description>- 3A</Description> 
 <code>17010210</code> 
 <County>Flathead</County> 
 <Station_ID>C09SHEPC04</Station_ID> 
</plan>
</XMLReview>
```

The HTML

```
<form>
 <input type="button" id="btnxml" value="XML" onclick="getXML()" />

   ID <input type="text" name="ID" id="ID">       
   planNumber<input type="text" name="Name" id="planNumber"> 
   area<input type="text" name="Area" id="Area">
   Name:  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
   Description:  <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description">
   Station ID  <input type="text" name="Station_ID" id="Station_ID">
   <label class="Code-label" for="code">HUC</label>
    <select class="select_code" id="code" name="code" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
      <option></option>
      <option>  10010001</option>
      <option>  10010002</option>
      <option>  10020001</option>
    </select>
   <label class="county-label" for="County">County</label>
    <select class="select_county" id="County" name="County" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
     <option></option>
     <option>   Beaverhead </option>
     <option>   Big Horn    </option>
     <option>   Blaine  </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The script

```
<script>
  function getXML()
 {
 $.get("XMLReview.xml", function(data) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "XMLReview.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      var select = $('#ID');
        $(xml).find('plan').each(function () {
        var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
        select.append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
        $("#ID").change(function () {
            var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected'));
            var newOpt = $(xml).find("values").eq(selectedIndex).find('value').each(function () {
                var value = $(this).text();
            });
         });
      }
    }); 
  alert(data);});
 }

</script>
```

Unfortunataly this is not working and I don't know why. Can anyone help me please

Comment: You realize that the element with the ID `#ID` is just a regular text input that can't have any options ?

Comment: You are missing a `);` after the closing bracket of this line: `$(xml).find('plan').each(function () {`  Fixing this doesn't entirely solve your question though, I'm working on a JSFiddle that shows you everything you need to address

Comment: Your XML doesn't include any node with the name `value`

Answer (score 0):

One or two things:

You are specifying the onclick event inline:

```
<input type="button" id="btnxml" value="XML" onclick="getXML()" />
```

Why not keep everything in one place -- since you already are using quite a bit of jQuery. Just add it to the javascript block like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnxml" value="XML" />
```

and

```
$('#btnxml').click(function() {
    getXML();
});
```

---

Without checking your javascript/ajax code, this construction is wrong:

```
function getXML(){
    $.get("XMLReview.xml", function(data) {   <<======= REMOVE
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "XMLReview.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                var select = $('#ID');
                $(xml).find('plan').each(function () {
                    var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
                    select.append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
                    $("#ID").change(function () {
                        var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected'));
                            var newOpt = $(xml).find("values").eq(selectedIndex).find('value').each(function () {
                            var value = $(this).text();
                        }); //END $(xml).find.eq.find.each
                    }); //END #ID.change
                }); //END $(xml).find.each
                alert(data);
            } //END AJAX.success fn
        }); //END $.ajax
    }); //END $.get  <<=================================== REMOVE
}
```

It should look like this:

```
function getXML(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "XMLReview.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var select = $('#ID');
            $(xml).find('plan').each(function () {
                var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
                select.append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
                $("#ID").change(function () {
                    var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected'));
                        var newOpt = $(xml).find("values").eq(selectedIndex).find('value').each(function () {
                        var value = $(this).text();
                    }); //END $(xml).find.eq.find.each
                }); //END #ID.change
            }); //END $(xml).find.each
            alert(data);
        } //END AJAX.success fn
    }); //END $.ajax
}
```

*The extra $.get() wrapper is unnecessary.*

Note that `$.ajax()` and `$.get()` and `$.post()` do the same thing. You are using the more structured `$.ajax()` construction, which is (IMHO) easier to keep things straight.

`$.get()` simply hard-codes the `type="GET"` and `$.post()` hard-codes the `type="POST"`

---

Also, I haven't done much with the XML dataType, but I strongly suspect that `xml` -- in the success function of your AJAX code block, in this context:

```
success: function (xml) {
    //post ajax code here, for eg.
    alert(xml);
}
```

Is a variable that will contain whatever has been ECHOed/printed/etc from the server side script? I don't believe it's an XML `object`...

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are kind of a lot of things going on here so I figured a fresh implementation would be easier to understand than a series of corrections (I'll try and note places where your understanding of JavaScript might need some work)  First a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9eqvq/).  Now the JavaScript:

```
$('#btnxml').on('click', function() {
    var select = $('#ID'),
        xml = $($.parseXML($('#XMLData').text())),
        plans = xml.find('plan');

    plans.each(function () {
        var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
        select.append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
    });

    $("#ID").change(function () {
        var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected')),
            plan = $(plans[selectedIndex]);

        $('#planNumber').val(plan.find('planNumber').text());
        $('#Area').val(plan.find('Area').text());
        $('#Name').val(plan.find('Name').text());
        $('#Description').val(plan.find('Description').text());
        $('#Station_ID').val(plan.find('Station_ID').text());

        $('#code').val(plan.find('code').text());
        $('#County').val(plan.find('County').text());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

And then the HTML

```
<script type='text/xml' id='XMLData'>
  <XMLReview>
    <plan>
      <planNumber>773</planNumber> 
      <Area>Upper Missouri</Area> 
      <ID>MISSOURI-NUT</ID> 
      <Name>Missouri River</Name> 
      <code>10030101</code> 
      <County>Broadwater</County> 
      <Station_ID>M09MISSR05</Station_ID> 
    </plan>
    <plan>
      <planNumber>774</planNumber> 
      <Area>Columbia</Area> 
      <ID>FLAT-STILL-TPA-2013</ID> 
      <Name>Sheppard Creek</Name> 
      <Description>- 3A</Description> 
      <code>17010210</code> 
      <County>Flathead</County> 
      <Station_ID>C09SHEPC04</Station_ID> 
    </plan>
  </XMLReview>
</script>
<form>
    <input type="button" id="btnxml" value="XML" /><br/>
    ID <select type="text" name="ID" id="ID"></select><br/>
    planNumber<input type="text" name="Name" id="planNumber"><br/>
    area<input type="text" name="Area" id="Area"><br/>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"><br/>
    Description:  <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description"><br/>
    Station ID  <input type="text" name="Station_ID" id="Station_ID"><br/>
    <label class="Code-label" for="code">HUC</label>
    <select class="select_code" id="code" name="code" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
      <option></option>
      <option>10010001</option>
      <option>10010002</option>
      <option>10020001</option>
      <option>10030101</option>
      <option>17010210</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label class="county-label" for="County">County</label>
    <select class="select_county" id="County" name="County" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
     <option></option>
     <option>Beaverhead</option>
     <option>Big Horn</option>
     <option>Blaine</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

First, I made these changes to make this easier to demonstrate in JSFiddle, but they don't necessarily match what your final code will be:

- I faked the AJAX request (the other answer here gives you a clear explanation of how to properly use jQuery's excellent AJAX helper methods).  When rolling this answer into yours you can just assume that all of this is wrapped in a `$.get()` that fetches your XML remotely.
- I also bound the `click` handled in JavaScript to `$('#btnxml')` (this is cleaner, but also because JSFiddle doesn't like onclick attributes that point to named functions), this is not strictly wrong it's just cleaner.

Now for the substantive changes:

- You are really trying to do two things, populate your `$('#ID')` selector (which was originally a `<input type='text'>` which is incorrect, in this code I updated to to a `<select>`, and then after it's populated you are trying to bind a `change` event handler.  You had these steps inside each other, and I separated them back out.  Also programmaticly changing a `<select>` doesn't trigger a change event automatically, so I appended a `.trigger('change')` at the end.
- It also appears that you are attempting to take the child nodes of the selected plan and update the corresponding `input` with the same name.  You could use the `.childNodes` property but this will include `TextNodes` for all of the white-space between XML nodes, and rather than trying to filter them out I thought it would be cleaner to just map them individually.  This may not work for you if your HTML and XML are constantly being updated but the next point I'm going to make possibly would prevent a totally automatic approach anyways.
- Selecting an option based on a value presents some challenges.  jQuery is very smart.  If you have a `<select>` element with a set of options that don't have `value` attributes and you try and set that `<select>` element's `.val()` by a string of one of those `<option>`s inside that element it will do the right thing.  However if there are no elements that match that value then it will silently pass over it.  Your XML has code and County values that do not appear in your HTML.  I added the missing code values to show you that it is working, but I didn't add them to the County `<select>`.  If you know all of your possible codes and county's and you can update your HTML then this won't be a problem, if instead you want new values to be appended while old values are just selected, then your code will get a little trickier.

Comment: Your guys are amazing! Your applications for sainthood are in the mail!

Comment: Just updated my answer.  That's about all I've got in me at the moment, hope it helps :)

Comment: so if I am accessing a remote file it should look like this? function getXML(){ $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "XMLReview.xml", dataType: "xml", success: function (xml) { var select = $('#ProjectID'), xml = $($.parseXML($('#XMLData').text())), Workplans = xml.find('Workplan'); (etc.)

Comment: You wouldn't need the `$.parseXML()` and the `$('#XMLData').text()` is actually to extract that bit of XML from the HTML.

Comment: So this whole line goes away? xml = $($.parseXML($('#XMLData').text())),   (can you tell I am completely new to this:-))

Comment: Yes. To both questions :) you can actually kind of reason about what this line is doing. The inner selector is finding the element with the id "XMLData", then .text() is extracting its contents. Then $.parseXML() is parsing it into a XML document and the outermost $() is turning it into a jquery object with properties like .find() and .each(). When you use $.ajax() with a data type of XML it does these steps for you

Comment: Well I've tried and tried but can't seem to get this to work. Does it make a difference that I am using JQuery Mobile? The Select ID creates a popup and it isn't being populated. Is there a way around this